# Get missed transactions from slave

Tags: mysql, replication, failover, disaster-recovery, mysqlbinlog

I'm trying to write a disaster recovery plan, I have one way replication with 1 master(A) and 3 slaves(B,C,D)

```
     A 
    /|\
   / | \
  B  C  D
```

Let's say my master crash, and I loose all data on that server, I still have 3 slaves, and I'll promote the most up-to-date to be my new master, let say slave B is up to date and C and D are not, at the point I promote B to master my slaves have the follow result for `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`:

```
slaveB> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
      Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000002
        Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1476884

slaveC> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
      Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000002
        Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 78684

slaveD> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
      Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000001
        Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 746848
```

In order to promote B to master, I want to apply all missing transactions on C and D, so before B become the new master and start to receive queries from applications, I've all slaves on a consistent state, how can I find the missed transactions from C and D on binary logs from B (I've the `--log-slave-updates` option enabled on all server).

For legacy issues, the envoirement use MySQL 5.0

Comment: Please run `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` from each Slave and post that output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you need to do to change, what I will call, the reference point for replication.

Since Servers B,C, and D have binlogs enabled, this will be handy.

You gave

```
slaveB> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
      Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000002
        Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1476884

slaveC> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
      Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000002
        Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 78684
```

Let's sync up ServerC to be a Slave to ServerB

**STEP 01 : Stop all writes to ServerC**

```
STOP SLAVE;
```

**STEP 02 : On ServerC, run `SHOW MASTER STATUS;`**

Let's say the output was master-bin.000003 position 12345678

**STEP 03 : On ServerC, run**

```
mysqlbinlog master-bin.000003 > latest-binlog.sql
```

**STEP 04 : Locate position from `STEP 03` and show 3 lines before and after**

```
grep -C 3 12345678 latest-binlog.sql
```

Let's say the timestamp was "2013-09-03 01:23:45"

**STEP 05 : Find the timestamp of that position in the binary logs of ServerB**

Let's say the binary log on ServerB is master-bin.000004

**STEP 06 : Dump position matching timestamp inside ServerB's binary log master-bin.000004**

```
SQLFILE=dumpstuff.sql
BINLOG="master-bin.000004"
DT2="2013-09-03 01:23:45"
DT1="2013-09-03 01:00:00"
mysqlbinlog --start-datetime="${DT1}" --stop-datetime="${DT2}" > ${SQLFILE}
```

**STEP 07 : Locate the timestamp inside `SQLFILE` and find the position**

Let's say the position is 87654321

**STEP 08 : Connect SlaveC to SlaveB**

On SlaveC, run this

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO master_log_file='master-bin.000004',master_log_pos=87654321;
START SLAVE;
```

**That's it !!!**

## CAVEAT #1

Repeats all these same steps to sync ServerD to ServerB

## CAVEAT #2

If you have done these steps and still don't trust the data, please download Percona Tools and use [pt-table-checksum](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-checksum.html) to verify each Slave against the new Master. If there are differences, you can run [pt-table-sync](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-sync.html) to generate the SQL to repair the differences.

## UPDATE 2013-09-05 12:28 EDT

You just made this comment

> On Step 2,3 and 4 , I don't have access to master binlog, I guess the way to get the latest applied transaction on slaveC is to extract it (using the Relay_Master_Log_File and Exec_Master_Log_Pos from show slave status) from slaveC relay log. Am I right? Steps 5 to 8 seems to be correct.

You can use [**mysqlbinlog**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html) remotely using [**--read-from-remote-server**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_read-from-remote-master). Besides, you do not go back to the old Master, ServerA. You are doing these things among the Slaves, making ServerB the new Master. If you are using some manged hosting company, those admins need to be involved in this process. At the very least, they could provide some SSH tunnel access to permit you to access the Linux box and all necessary folders permissions. No MySQL authentication is needed.

Comment: On Step 2,3 and 4 , I don't have access to master binlog, I guess the way to get the latest applied transaction on slaveC is to extract it (using the `Relay_Master_Log_File ` and `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` from `show slave status`) from slaveC relay log. Am I right?
Steps 5 to 8 seems to be correct.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment...

Comment: `--read-from-remote-master` was added in MySQL 5.6.5, and the OP is using 5.0.  :-(

Comment: @BillKarwin the option is in MySQL 5.0 as well : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_read-from-remote-server. It has `-R` option with it. The option is read-from-remote-server. I didn't notice it myself until I actually looked. Thank you for the second set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

May I know if there is a reason why we need to find from binary logs instead of data folder sync (`rsync`)? Since the application have not started writing to B, I think, we have the luxury to even stop the MySQL server and run a clean `rsync` (data is too very big, maybe?). I have first hand experience following this method and it worked like a charm. When we read binlogs (read human intervention in counting the position), we may end up with a wrong position and in worst case, we'll be dealing with duplicate entries.